# unity Bicycle pedal sync animation script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm trying to animate my Bicycle model in Unity, since i used animation rig with the biker model and i was able to animate it with the following code.

```
    private void RotateRightFoot(
    float in_deltatime
)
{
    Vector3 targetPos = 
                _rightPositions[_rightIndex].localPosition;
    Vector3 curPos = 
                _RightFootTarget.transform.localPosition;
    targetPos.z = 
                curPos.z;
    float step =
                _speed * in_deltatime;
    Vector3 newRot = 
                Vector3.MoveTowards(curPos,targetPos,step);
    
    _RightFootTarget.localPosition = 
                                newRot;

    if( curPos == targetPos )
    {
        _rightIndex++;

        if( _rightIndex >= _positions.Length )
        {
            _rightIndex = 0;
        }

        _startRightPos = 
                    targetPos;
    }
}
```

with the above code i'm moving the right foot around Bicycle pedal, but now i want to sync the pedal to biker foot movement, and since i'm not good at math i have no idea to how accomplish it.

i have a pvot on pedale so what i have to do it's just rotate it, but i don't have idea how much..

Comment: I recently got into _Wheel Colliders_ which had a similar issue between the _collider, wheel_ and _suspension_.  I found that rather than update the position of the shock absorber via code it is was much easier to simply use a _[Position Constraint](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PositionConstraint.html)_.  There are similar constraints for parenting and rotation.  **No code required**.  They `also allow you to do things not normally possible` like _multiple parents, not affected by scale, does not have to belong to original object etc_

Comment: well i ended up using UMotion tool instead unity build in animation tool why the unity build in one won't rotate object on 360 degrees they go from -180 to 180, so thats why i was using a script instead simple animation.

Comment: Glad you found a solution.  Don't forget, you can post below what you performed to solve your problem thus answering your _own question_.  You can even "accept" it earning reputation if no other better solution comes along.  Good luck!